# Cannot create multiple instances of PowerPoint

Tags: c#, powerpoint

I'm working on a project where I need to use PowerPoint from C#.net. Initially, I always created one single instance. As of today, I would like to have multiple instance running. I do that like so:

```
Type powerpointType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("PowerPoint.Application");

object instance1 = Activator.CreateInstance(powerpointType);
object instance2 = Activator.CreateInstance(powerpointType);
```

but when I ask for the handle of both instances, by calling

```
hwnd = (int)powerpointType.GetProperty("HWND").GetValue(instance1, null);
```

then I get the same handle twice. My conclusion is that the application is started just once, and the TaskManager comfirms that: Only one process.

How come there is only one instance of PowerPoint running, and how can I make it work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of multiple instances, why not reference the multiple open presentations in the single instance?

When a user "Quits a column," you can just close that one presentation, but leave PPT open, unless it is the last open presentation.

Answer (score 4):

[This link](http://pleasemakeanote.blogspot.com/2008/06/multiple-instances-of-powerpoint.html) discusses how to use a new user account to create multiple instances of PowerPoint.  It works fine if you're always running it off the same computer, but isn't particularly easy to distribute.

Comment: This wouldn't be preferable, since the app is going to be distributed amongst hundreds of users, possibly with low to no computer skills.

Answer (score 2):

PowerPoint as well as Word shares the same instance. Excel on the other hand lets you have multiple instances. In order to have two instances running you need to start up the other instance as a different user.

Why do you need multiple instances? In order to show two presentations on two monitors?

Comment: The app I'm writing is (among a lot of other things) for presenting PowerPoint Presentations. If you add a presentation to a column (kind of working area), that column should be filled with thumbnails of the slide of the ppt. There for I need PowerPoint. After that, one can present the ppt. That also launches PowerPoint. These things should be able to happen at the same time, and you should be able to open a ppt while also quitting another column with a ppt.

Comment: I think you then need to run two instances under different users, or use PowerPoint from Office 2010 (beta) which is supposed to work with multiple windows.

Comment: @MikaelSvenson Powerpoint share 1 instance, Word and Excel do not share 1 instance.

Comment: @Paul, back in 2010 when I wrote my answer, this was how it worked. I guess I tested with either Office 2007 or 2010. Have not checkednit lately with 2013. And word and excel does not share the same instance, if that is how you read my answer. But opening word multiple times will share the same instance.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comment to Mikael, there is another solution. This is VBA, but easily portable to C#. Just open the presentation (hidden) and export each slide as a PNG. Then you can have those PNGs display in your column.

```
Dim ap As Presentation
Set ap = Presentations.Open(FileName:="yourppt.pptx", WithWindow:=msoFalse)
Dim s As Slide
For Each s In ap.Slides
    s.Export s.Name, "PNG"
Next
```

Then, when someone clicks something, the first one can close and your new PPT can show.

Comment: I use this technique for in the columns already, but it does not suffice for showing, because it ignores animations on slides, and just shows the first/last state.

Comment: @Excel20: Yeah, that was the intent - you can have a light weight way of showing the slides in the column and then you can load your deck.

Answer (score -1):

For 2007 users save a ppt(x) as a pdf

At least pdf can be opened as separate instances

You can save back as .doc (my version of Acrobat Pro is 9.5.2); the .doc is OK but not perfect, but a least I can cut and paste between the .doc and the .ppt(x) :-)

BTW - Word 2007 does open each document as a separate instance, at least in my installation, the install being done by our IT folks.